# Add text distance output to ggplot2 geom_step() function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to add a text output showing the length of the segments created by geom_step dynamically? I figured out how to add columns showing both the vertical and horizontal distances below.

```
ex <- structure(list(Type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"
), Hz = c(50, 550, 1050, 800, 300, 50, 550, 1050), Vert = c(500, 
500, 550, 600, 600, 700, 750, 700)), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")


ex <- ex %>% arrange(Hz) %>%
  mutate(HzText= abs(Hz - lag(Hz, default = first(Hz)))) %>%
  arrange(Hz)%>%mutate(VtText= abs(Vert - lag(Vert, default = first(Vert)))) %>%
  mutate(HzMidpt= abs(Hz - lag(Hz, default = first(Hz)))/2+lag(Hz, default = first(Hz)))%>%
  mutate(VtMidpt= abs(Vert - lag(Vert, default = first(Vert)))/2+lag(Vert, default = first(Vert)))

ggplot(ex, aes(Hz,Vert, color=Type,group=1))+geom_step(color='black')+geom_point(size=5)+theme_minimal()+scale_y_reverse()+
  annotate("text",x=44,y=550,label='100',angle=90)+
  annotate("text",x=44,y=650,label='100',angle=90)+
  annotate("text",x=160,y=695,label='250')+
  annotate("text",x=300,y=650,label='100',angle=90)
```

Thanks!

Comment: A very quick try with this, using your calculated mids, 
g + geom_label(data=ex[-1,],aes(x=HzMidpt,y=VtMidpt,label=paste(HzText,VtText,sep=",")),col="black")

Comment: I think you have to think about where to put the label

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. I just want to show the segment lengths as a text in addition to the segment lines.

Comment: Hmm I cannot quite grasp what you need.. Maybe one example?

Comment: I've updated the code to render what I'd like the plot labels to look like manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll rename the columns to avoid confusion:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
ex <- 
  tibble(
    type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
    x = c(50, 550, 1050, 800, 300, 50, 550, 1050),
    y = c(500, 500, 550, 600, 600, 700, 750, 700)
  )
```

`geom_step` splits the path from one point to another into x-shift (comes first) and y-shift. We'll do the same: calculate these shifts and create one row for each of the two directions. Zero-shifts will be excluded.

For each shift we'll need to correctly calculate the positions at which we want to place labels describing these shifts (`label_x` and `label_y`).

```r
labels_df <-
  ex %>% 
  arrange(x, y) %>% 
  mutate(
    prev_x = lag(x, default = first(x)),
    prev_y = lag(y, default = first(y)),
    shift_x = x - prev_x,
    shift_y = y - prev_y
  ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = matches("shift"),
    names_to = "direction",
    names_prefix = "shift_"
  ) %>% 
  filter(value != 0) %>% 
  mutate(
    label_x = case_when(
      direction == "x" ~ (x + prev_x)/2,
      direction == "y" ~ x
    ),
    label_y = case_when(
      direction == "x" ~ prev_y,
      direction == "y" ~ y - value/2
    )    
  ) %>% 
  mutate(label_text = as.character(abs(value))) %>% 
  mutate(angle = if_else(direction == "x", 0, 90))

labels_df
#> # A tibble: 11 x 11
#>    type      x     y prev_x prev_y direction value label_x label_y
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 C        50   700     50    500 y           200      50     600
#>  2 B       300   600     50    700 x           250     175     700
#>  3 B       300   600     50    700 y          -100     300     650
#>  4 A       550   500    300    600 x           250     425     600
#>  5 A       550   500    300    600 y          -100     550     550
#>  6 C       550   750    550    500 y           250     550     625
#>  7 B       800   600    550    750 x           250     675     750
#>  8 B       800   600    550    750 y          -150     800     675
#>  9 A      1050   550    800    600 x           250     925     600
#> 10 A      1050   550    800    600 y           -50    1050     575
#> 11 C      1050   700   1050    550 y           150    1050     625
#> # ... with 2 more variables: label_text <chr>, angle <dbl>
```

Now we can add labels to the plot with `geom_text` using this dataframe.

```r
ggplot(ex, aes(x, y, color = type, group = 1)) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_step(color = "black") +
  geom_text(data = labels_df, aes(label_x, label_y, label = label_text, angle = angle),
            color = "gray30") +
  coord_fixed() + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

This actually can be improved. Consider for example the rightmost two points. It would make more sense to label 100 vertical shift from the horizontal line to the blue point rather than 150 shift from the red point to the blue point. Such places in the plot can be described as:

- the shift is vertical (`direction == "y"`)
- the previous shift was also vertical
- the previous shift has the opposite sign

This can be fixed with:

```r
labels_df <- 
  labels_df %>% 
  mutate(fix_y_label = direction == "y" & lag(direction) == "y" & 
           sign(value) != sign(lag(value)) & row_number() != 1) %>% 
  mutate(
    label_y    = ifelse(fix_y_label, label_y - lag(value)/2, label_y),
    label_text = ifelse(fix_y_label, as.character(abs(value + lag(value))), label_text)
  )
```

Note: this covers all the cases only if the initial dataframe was sorted by x and then y. (`arrange(x, y)`)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update. I like your workflow. I had been trying to reverse engineer of geom_step to get a similar output.